# C# куда вынести однородные данные из класса

Tags: c#

Пишу программу, которая работает с файлами книг (на данный момент epub,fb2,fb3). 
Есть класс Book с конкретной информацией о каждой книге.
Есть статический класс который собственно и обрабатывает все эти книги и результат заносит в List для дальнейшей работы.

Для обработки файлов используется по сути один и тот же код, только данные отличаются в зависимости от формата файла. например в epub надо открыть файл по патчу "content.opf", у fb3 по патчу "fb3/description.xml", а у fb2 вообще отсутствует (допустимо записать пустой "" патч). И таких различных параметров на данный момент 8.

Вопрос, где можно хранить эту информацию, которая относится не к конкретной книге, а к формату книги. Можно ли сделать статический класс с этой информацией, чтобы не создавать экземпляр класса? Ведь он просто хранит информацию, никаких действий с ней делать не надо. 
Хочется понять, как это сделать корректнее и правильнее.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно реализовать через абстрактный класс, в котором будет общая логика, и при необходимости вы сможете в классе наследнике переопределить то, что вам нужно, в зависимости от условий. Например, код может выглядеть так:

Для начала создаем общий интерфейс для всех книг

```
public interface IBook
{
    string Title { get; set; }
}
```

После создаем модели для двух типов книг

```
public class Book1 : IBook
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
public class Book2 : IBook
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

Далее создаем абстрактный класс, в котором будет общая логика

```
public abstract class BookExample<T>
    where T : class, IBook
{
    // Указываем нашу переменную, которую необходимо реализовать
    public abstract string FilePath { get; set; }

    // Реализуем все методы, например метод чтения
    protected virtual void Read()
    {
        var text = File.ReadAllText(FilePath);
    }
}
```

И наконец, создаем классы, для наших двух типов книг

```
public class TestBook1 : BookExample<Book1>
{
    public override string FilePath { get; set; } = "filePath1";
}

public class TestBook2 : BookExample<Book2>
{
    public override string FilePath { get; set; } = "filePath2";

    protected override void Read()
    {
        // переопределяем класс, если такое необходимо
        base.Read();
    }
}
```

Comment: Экземпляры каких из этих классов в таком случае создавать? если я прохожу по каталогу и все файлы книг сохраняю по одному шаблону, теперь придется перед сохранением проверять формат файла и создавать экземпляр соответствующего класса?

Comment: @NK а в чем проблема? создаете объект того класса, который сможет обработать ваш запрос. Добавить только надо будет еще интерфейс один и все

Comment: Проблемы нет, я просто узнавал, правильно ли я понял принцип действия. В общем я разобрался во всем, спасибо за направление моих мыслей!)

Answer (score 0):

### Вариант 1 то что вы хотели статичный класс

```
    public static class GlobalConfig
    {
        public static string path1 { get { return @"c:\content.opf"; } }
        public static string path2 { get { return @"d:\"; } }

    }
```

### Вариант 2 switch

```
public string GetmyPath()
    {
        string filePath;
        using (OpenFileDialog opf = new OpenFileDialog())
        {
            if (opf.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                filePath = opf.FileName;
                string extention = Path.GetExtension(filePath); // получаем расширение файла .exe , .txt

                switch (extention)
                {
                    case ".txt":
                    {
                        Process.Start("notepad.exe", filePath); // октрываем тектовые документы через notpad
                        return filePath;
                    }
                    case ".opf": // что делать если файл с .opf
                    {
                        return GlobalConfig.path1


                    }
                    case ".xml": // что делать если файл с .xml
                    {
                        // десериализация ?

                        break;
                    }


                    default:
                    {
                        return string.Empty;
                    }
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        return String.Empty;
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо за комментарий! Однако после долгих раздумий понял, что статический класс не удобен, а от оператора switch вовсе желательно отказаться, т.к. здесь хорошо применим полиморфизм (как у другого комментатора)